# Duplicate property 'Style' setter

Tags: wpf, styling

I want to be able to style my grid like this:

```
<DataGrid Style="{DynamicResource BilagDatagridStyle}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But I can't figure out the correct syntax for setting the datagridcell style, I am getting an error on Property="DataGridCell.Style" complaning that it's the same setter as Property="DataGridRow.Style" the error is: Duplicate property 'Style' setter

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultReadOnlyGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}"  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single"/>
    <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="30"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="BilagDatagridStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultReadOnlyGridStyle}">
    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Style" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridRowNoInteractionStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="DataGridRow.Style" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridRowNoInteractionStyle}"/>
</Style>
```

I know that there is a way to do it, but how?

Answer (score 1):

When you specify TargetType there is no need to add UIelement's name in property name. In your case appropiate is CellStyle and RowStyle, but if you get rid of TargetType then you have to use DataGrid.CellStyle/DataGrid.RowStyle.

```
<Style x:Key="YourCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
</Style>
<Style x:Key="YourRowStyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
</Style>

<Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource YourCellStyle}"/>
<Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource YourRowStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks I started with what your are suggestion, but could't make it compile before I put TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" I don't know why I need that when the style is based on a style that's target the data grid. But thanks for putting me back on track